# jQuery - all elements on page to array

Tags: jquery, font-size

Anyone knows how to put all of the elements on the page into array?

I want to loop throug all of them and increase the font size relatively to the currently set one.

Thanks

Comment: would be better to create a good CSS map in order to ease the proccess. Looping through all the elements may take a "while"

Answer (score 9):

First, you can do this with the [universal selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/) `$('*')`.  However, **do not do this**.  Whatever you are trying to do, this is the wrong way to do it.

You should do this by setting all your fonts to be relative to a base size (using percentages or `em`s) and changing the global (`body`) font-size.  That would have far, far better performance.

Comment: Yes - but how can I actually put all of them into array - say I would only want the items inside of the #container div to be added to array and then increase font size of all elements inside of this container.

Comment: Then increase the size of the font in #container. If the elements have some kind of logical relationship in your page, don't change them individually. That way madness lies.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is like this.

```
$('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to rack up this oldie, but I was searching for a solution and I have found it.
I hope others might still find this usefull:

1. Make sure your font-sizes are expressed as % or em

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //currentsize is the percentage of all elements within the body or container
    var currentsize = 100;
    //function when a button is clicked orso
    function sizeIncrease(){
        //increase the percentage of fontsize by 10
        currentsize = currentsize + 10;
        //apply the new fontsize to all elements within another element (here body)
        $('body').css('fontSize', currentsize+'%');
    }
</script>
```